# Making the DOM aware of Dynamically Created Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have a process that needs to use dynamically added objects. How do I access these objects in Jquery.

Current: Not displaying the two div tags '#transferorProfileGroups' and '#transfereeProfile' When the transtypesvalue is equal to "transfer in" or "transfer out".

Results I want: To display or hide these div tags when conditions are met.

```
var JSON = JSON || {};
// implement JSON.stringify serialization
JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function (obj) {
var t = typeof (obj);
if (t != "object" || obj === null) {
    // simple data type
    if (t == "string")
        obj = '"' + obj + '"';
    return String(obj);
} else {
    // recurse array or object
    var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);
    for (n in obj) {
        v = obj[n];
        t = typeof (v);
        if (t == "string")
            v = '"' + v + '"';
        else if (t == "object" && v !== null)
            v = JSON.stringify(v);
        json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));R
    }
    return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
}
};

$(document).ready(function () {
setJobExceptionDataTable();

handleTransferTypeSelection();

});

function handleTransferTypeSelection() {
$('#tranTypes').live('change' , function () {
alert("help")
    var transfertypesvalue = $(this).val();

    if (transfertypesvalue == "Transfer In") {
        $('#transferorProfileGroups]').removeClass('invisible');
        $('#transfereeProfile').addClass('invisible'); 

    }
    else if (transfertypesvalue == "Transfer Out") {
        $('#transfereeProfile').removeClass('invisible');
        $('#transferorProfileGroups').addClass('invisible');
    }
    else {
        $('#transfereeProfile').addClass('invisible');
        $('#transferorProfileGroups').addClass('invisible');
    }
});
}

function getJobExceptionDetails(jobId, jobName, jobStatus, jobSubmitted, jobExceptionType) {
var getDetailsUrl = '';
var setTables = '';

switch (jobExceptionType) {
    case "ProfileSelectionRequired":
        setTables = setProfileSelectionRequiredDataTables;
        getDetailsUrl = "/JobException/GetProfileSelectionRequiredDetails";
        break;
    default:
        alert('JobExceptionType not defined. (' + jobExceptionType + ')');
        return false;
        break;
}

$.ajax({
    url: getDetailsUrl,
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        JobId: jobId,
        JobStatus: jobStatus,
        JobSubmitted: jobSubmitted,
        JobName: jobName,
        JobExceptionType: jobExceptionType
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#loading').show();
    },
    success: function (result) {
        $(".detailsModalContent").append(result);

        setTables();

        $("#detailsModal").modal({
            autoResize: true,
            autoPostition: true,
            closeHTML: "",
            dataCss: {
                padding: "10px"
            },
            minHeight: 350,
            maxHeight: 700,
            minWidth: 900,
            maxWidth: 900,
            overlayClose: true
        });

        $("#btnResolveProfileSelectionRequired").click(function () {
            handleResolveProfileSelectionRequired();
        });

        $('.datepicker').datepicker();

        $('input[type=checkbox][name=profilegroup]').change(function () {
            checked = $(this).attr('checked');
            if (checked) {
                $('input[type=checkbox][name=profilegroup]').removeAttr('checked');
                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve items, please try again.');
    },
    complete: function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
    }
});
}



function handleResolveProfileSelectionRequired() {
var valid = true;
var msg = '';

var notEmpty = /\S/

var transferEffectiveDate = $("#TransferEffectiveDate").val();
if (!notEmpty.test(transferEffectiveDate)) {
    msg += "Please select a transfer effective date.\r\n";
    valid = false;
}

var selectedGroup = $("select[name='profileGroups']").val();
if (selectedGroup == undefined || selectedGroup <= 0) {
    msg += "Please select a transferor profile group.\r\n";
}

if (!valid) {
    alert(msg);
} else {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/JobException/ResolveProfileSelectionRequired/",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken:       $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(),
            JobId: $("#JobException_JobId").val(),
            TransferEffectiveDate: transferEffectiveDate,
            SelectedTransferorProfileGroupId: selectedGroup
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#loading').show();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            window.location.reload();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Failed to resolve profile selection required job exception, please try again.');
            window.location.reload();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
}
}

function setJobExceptionDataTable() {
aoColumnsObject =
[
    {
        "sName": "JobId",
        "sType": "numeric",
        "fnRender": function (oObj) {

            var jobId = oObj.aData[0];
            var jobName = oObj.aData[1];
            var jobSubmitted = oObj.aData[2];
            var jobStatus = oObj.aData[3];

            return '<a href="/" class="detailsLink"' + '" jobid="' + jobId + '" jobname="' + jobName + '" jobstatus="' + jobStatus + '" jobsubmitted="' + jobSubmitted + '">' + jobId + "</a>";
        }
    },
    { "sName": "JobName" },
    { "sName": "JobSubmitted", "sType": "date" },
    { "sName": "JobStatus" }
];

var oTable = $("#orderQueueTable").dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/JobException/GetJobExceptionItems/",
    "bProcessing": false,
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        aoData.push({ "name": "jobExceptionType", "value": $("#JobExceptionType").val()       });

        $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "GET",
            "url": sSource,
            "data": aoData,
            "beforeSend": function () {
                $("#loading").removeClass('invisible');
            },
            "success": fnCallback,
            "complete": function () {
                $(".detailsLink").live('click', function () {
                    getJobExceptionDetails($(this).attr('jobid'), $(this).attr('jobname'), $(this).attr('jobstatus'), $(this).attr('jobsubmitted'), $("#JobExceptionType").val());
                    return false;
                });

                $("#loading").addClass('invisible');
            }
        });
    },
    "aoColumns": aoColumnsObject,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bAutoWidth": false
});
}

function setProfileSelectionRequiredDataTables() {
$("#orderInfoTable").dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": "date" },
            null
        ]
});
```

}

and here is the html:

```
@model MarylinMonroeMvcSite.Models.JobException.ProfileSelectionRequiredModel

<div class="float-left">Profile Selection Required Resolution</div>

<div class="float-right">Job Id: @Model.JobException.JobId</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<br />

<form method="post" target="/JobException/ResolveProfileSelectionRequired"     id="profileSelectionResolutionForm">

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JobException.JobId, new { value = Model.JobException.JobId })

<div>
    Job Id: @Model.JobException.JobId<br />
    Job Name: @Model.JobException.JobName<br />
    Job Submitted: @if (Model.JobException.JobSubmitted.HasValue)
    { @Model.JobException.JobSubmitted.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy                 HH:mm:ss") }<br />
    Job Status: @Model.JobException.JobStatus
</div>

<br />

<div id="transferTypes">
    Select Transfer Type:
    <select name="tranTypes" id="tranTypes">
        <option value="0">Please Choose Transfer Type</option>
        @foreach (var type in Model.TransferTypes)
        {
            <option value="@type.TypeId">@type.TypeDescription</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<br />

<div>
    Transfer Effective Date: 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.TransferEffectiveDate, new { @class = "datepicker" })
</div>

<br />

<div id="transferorProfileGroups" class="invisible">
    Select Transferor Profile Group<br />
    <select name="profileGroups">
        <option value="0">Please Choose Group</option>
        @foreach (var group in Model.TransferorProfileGroups)
        {
            <option value="@group.GroupId">@group.DisplayName</option>
        }

    </select>
</div>

<div id="transfereeProfile" class="invisible">
    Select Transferee Profile Group <br />
    <select name="transfereeGroups">
        <option value="0">Please Choose Group</option>
        @foreach (var feree in Model.TransfereeList)
        {
            <option value="@feree.TransfereeListId">@feree.TransfereeName</option>
        }
     </select>
  </div>

<br />

<div>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btnResolveProfileSelectionRequired" />
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: An explanation of what you are trying to do, what you are expecting and what you are getting would be useful.

Comment: On top of explaining what you are getting and hope to get, you may want to add an "html" tag and fix your "java" tag to "javascript" to get more views.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of 1.7, after which you should be using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, I made the changes you suggested. @Travesty I am currently using jquery 1.5.1

Comment: When do you call handleTransferTypeSelection function? Can you set up a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Unforunately I cannot put the documents on the web except for these small parts as it would go against my agreement with work. I did add where I call the handleTransferTypeSelection function though.

Comment: Is the change function fired (try with a console.log)? Any error in the console?

Comment: yes, the change function is fired. I put an alert after it to test it and it does fire, but after that nothing happens. I think it's because my "transfereeProfile" and  "transferorProfileGroups" are dynamically created. Therefor the DOM isn't aware of them, I just don't know how to fix that. Going to post the remainder of the HTML and JS to see if that helps me get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem was a little thing that I wasn't seeing. Since I could not use .on due to using an older version of Jquery I stuck with .live which worked fine. I just had my if statement searching for values instead of the labels. So the code went from:

```
function handleTransferTypeSelection() {
$('#tranTypes').live('change' , function () {
var transfertypesvalue = $(this).val();

if (transfertypesvalue == "Transfer In") {
    $('#transferorProfileGroups]').removeClass('invisible');
    $('#transfereeProfile').addClass('invisible'); 

}
else if (transfertypesvalue == "Transfer Out") {
    $('#transfereeProfile').removeClass('invisible');
    $('#transferorProfileGroups').addClass('invisible');
}
else {
    $('#transfereeProfile').addClass('invisible');
    $('#transferorProfileGroups').addClass('invisible');
}
});
}
```

and is now:

```
function handleTransferTypeSelection() {
$('#tranTypes').live('change' , function () {
var transfertypesvalue = $('#tranTypes option:selected').text();
                                        // ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ the changes
if (transfertypesvalue == "Transfer In") {
    $('#transferorProfileGroups]').removeClass('invisible');
    $('#transfereeProfile').addClass('invisible'); 

}
else if (transfertypesvalue == "Transfer Out") {
    $('#transfereeProfile').removeClass('invisible');
    $('#transferorProfileGroups').addClass('invisible');
}
else {
    $('#transfereeProfile').addClass('invisible');
    $('#transferorProfileGroups').addClass('invisible');
}
});
}
```

little things make all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery bindings like "live", "click" will bind to elements when the DOM finish its loading. Any elements that are AJAX response wont be bound to them. Instead you should use the ".on" method.

Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.my_new_element', function() {
    //your code here
});
```

That will work because ".on" is bound to the document and not a specific element. And since the 2nd parameter ('#my_new_element') is a filter the click event will only fire this function when performed on that element.

So as long as new HTML elements come via AJAX with that 'my_new_element' class on it they will fire your function when the event is performed on them.

Just for clarification: you don't need to bind to the "document". You could bind the ".on" method into any element that is guaranteed loaded before the AJAX is called. For example all your site is inside a `<div class="content"></div>` in this case you could bind like this:

```
$('.content').on('click', '.my_new_element', function() {
    //your code here
});
```